# Extact video file from quicktime web player

Tags: video-player, metadata

How can i extract video link form http://mediaservers.vtc.com:80/movieplayers/get_media_player.php?f=/photoshopcs5_fr/movies/02/0202.mov&vtclogin=U4646286

It is clearly seen that it is calling media file with ref. It does not start in web browser(ubuntu) but work with mac. I don't have plugin problem(gstreamer and restricted-extras are already installed). I need to extract the video file link. (java,python,c++ or any other scripting language)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you have there is not a video file link. It is a link to a php site which takes the a path to the video as an argument. This path however might as well be local on the remote server. Usually this is done to prevent you from doing what you intended to do. You can only try to run the link on your mac again and see whether there is a real URL in the site sent to you by the server. If not you wont easily get the video streamed into a file.

Comment: "You can only try to run the link on your mac again and see whether there is a real URL in the site sent to you by the server"  How could i? In mac it loads a player(web player) and run the file. How could i know the original link?

Comment: What do you want to say with that?

Comment: I am not sure where the server is. How do you know that it is a local remote server?

Comment: The server is not local.Everything after the '?' is an ARGUMENT for the php page request.This argument is passed to the php module which processes your request.The path after 'f=' might be a local path on the server which you might not be able to access.So you can only try to find the real path in the source code of the website which is sent to you when you request the url.

Comment: There may be another approach in extracting the video.
Depending on the browser, you might want to peak upon its tmp files, tho this might take some time

Comment: I need to automate the download. Means i have a text files with multiple links (similar with provided link), i need to download them one by one and save in a specific directory.  When load the link in mac it loads the video file and i can access the video file from browser cache. In this process it can not be downloaded automatically.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the provider of the videos for help on that ;-) Seems that you want to download many video files from this ressource, maybe he can provide you with a direct access to his ressources so that you can directly download everything you want.